Configure Kubernetes services of Spring Cloud Dataflow streams
When Spring Cloud Dataflow deploys a stream, it delegates the actual deployment to Spring Cloud Skipper. Effectively, it is possible to configure Skipper to customize the Kubernetes deployment, using this configuration properties. Yet, with the same properties, it is not possible to customize the Kubernetes service.
How is it possible to configure the Kubernetes service? Is it created during stream definition, but I'm unsure if it is generated by Skipper or directly by the Spring Cloud Dataflow server. In particular, I'm interested in having multiple ports exposed in the service.

Having multiple exposed ports will require a deployment property for the specific stream as follows:
deployment.<app-name>.kubernetes.servicePorts=5000,9000

Thank you for the answer. How are those ports mapped? What is the resulting name? The Kubernetes service is created before deployment, so I'm unsure how your solution will work.

Spring Cloud Data Flow uses Spring Cloud Deployer which uses Fabric8 for Kubernetes deployments. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/blob/0bb15f393b7cb664a8d28c76559a304d3e2b71d1/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/KubernetesAppDeployer.java#L357
